# insert same values into binomial heap

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-heap, binomial-heap

I have to insert some values into binomial heap. For example 25, 26, 24, 60, 65, 62. It will look like follows:
[image]

But then I have to insert 25, 68, 65 to the same heap. Should I insert 25 again or just skip it as it is already present in the heap?

Comment: Well that kinda depends on the requirements... There is no general rule.

Comment: So, it can contain duplicates?

Comment: AFAIK yes, the heap property says that the key of a node is greater than **or equal** to the key of its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to your implementation and specific requirements. Do you need duplicate elements? A binomial heap **can** support inserting the same value multiple times and will perform just as good(if you implement it correctly), but this does not mean that it **should** in your case.